# Interpret survival curve for multiple-event Cox proportional hazard model

Tags: r, survival, interpretation, cox-model, recurrent-events

I am using the `bladder2` dataset, which is setup in "conditional" long format:

```
data(bladder)

> head(bladder2)
  id rx number size start stop event enum
1  1  1      1    3     0    1     0    1
2  2  1      2    1     0    4     0    1
3  3  1      1    1     0    7     0    1
4  4  1      5    1     0   10     0    1
5  5  1      4    1     0    6     1    1
6  5  1      4    1     6   10     0    2
```

I then build a simple coxph model with stratification of the recurring event (denoted by `enum`):

```
library(survminer)

cox.model.cond = coxph(
  Surv(start, stop, event) ~ rx + number + size + strata(enum),
  data=bladder2
)
```

Then I plot the resultant survival curves:

```
ggsurvplot(survfit(cox.model.cond), data=bladder2)
```

[image]

How should I interpret these curves? 
 Specifically:

1. Even though events are sequential, does the plot indicate the average patient is at risk of 4x events at (almost) any time `t`?
2. If an average patient were currently at time `t=10` and they had not experienced any events, what would we say their probabilities of experiencing the events are in the next instant? the next 10 'steps' out?
3. Same question as above but what about a patient who has already experienced 1x event?
4. The lines for `enum=1` and `enum=2` cross.  How should this be interpreted, that the chance of 1x event occurring becomes less probable than the chance of the second event occurring?  That seems silly; I'm sure I have it wrong :)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure that we are reading the data situation similarly. As I understand it ... all of these patients have had at least one diagnosed episode of bladder cancer. The `coxph`-model you created with a `strata()`-constructed term yields this result using its print output:

```
cox.model.cond
#-----------
Call:
coxph(formula = Surv(start, stop, event) ~ rx + number + size + 
    strata(enum), data = bladder2)

            coef exp(coef)  se(coef)      z      p
rx     -0.333489  0.716420  0.216168 -1.543 0.1229
number  0.119617  1.127065  0.053338  2.243 0.0249
size   -0.008495  0.991541  0.072762 -0.117 0.9071

Likelihood ratio test=6.51  on 3 df, p=0.08928
n= 178, number of events= 112
```

Notice that there are no results for the individual strata. That's because the `strata` function basically separates the analysis into groups with separate baseline curves, but makes the assumption that the other covariates will have the same effects across strata relative to their separate baseline curves. This notion of homogeneity of effects across these strata seems to me  suspect and requiring great care before acceptance.

To the point of comparing different approaches to modeling recurrent events (also with bladder cancer data, but 10 times as much) see the paper, "[Prediction of Multiple Recurrent Events: A Comparison of Extended Cox Models in Bladder Cancer](https://academic.oup.com/aje/article/186/5/612/3836012)", by Hilde Smedinga in *American Journal of Epidemiology*.

To your separate questions:

1. Yes, I think that these results indicate an ongoing risk for all comers, However, I think it also indicates increasing risks for persons after a second or third episode.
2. (& 3) I'm going to assume that by an "event" you mean a second or third cancer. And an average patient would be one with  ... average size? average treatment? average "number" of sites? Or do you mean simply that we should consider all patients in the stratum? I'm going to assume the second option, since I think the answers to the first set of questions raise too many messy imponderables.

   To get the risk estimate for a member of the stratum you would take the decrement in survival divided by the time over which the decrement occurred and divide that by the starting survival fraction.
   $$
   \frac{ -\frac{d(S(t))}{dt} }{ S(t) }
   $$
   Generally one would smooth the survival fraction as a function of time ( S(t) ), and take the slope of the smoothed estimate as the numerator and the value of the smoothed estimate as the denominator. There are packages that will do that for you, and the `muhaz`-[package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/muhaz/index.html) for which I am the maintainer is one such. It would require data in the form of `(time, status)` rather than `(start, stop, status)`. There is a nice review of several packages for hazard estimation in Hagar & Dukic, [Comparison of hazard rate estimation in R](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.03253.pdf).

4. The crossing of the lines indicates that they could not be properly analyzed with a proportional hazards model that had a simple `enum` covariate. It is in point of fact the reason that a `strata` analysis needed to be done.

Comment: ahh - yes, my mistake (this data set assumes each patient has already experienced 1x event prior to study start).  And your point about separate baseline hazards per strata BUT common coefficients is well taken (that is a strong assumption).  This leads me to believe I would need to construct a multi-state model if I wanted to assess the effect of coefficients on transitions between first-and-second event, second-and-third event, and so on.  Can `muhaz` be used to extract the hazard rate for multi-state models?

Comment: If your the multi-state model is set up where each state can define a particular sub-population for which a time to exit or censor from the state can be defined, then muhaz can calculate for the extracted sub-population. It is not, however, going to do the data extraction or stratum formation for you. It's a rather bare bones package that is not even integrated with the survival package. It probably could be, but I didn't write it, only took it over to correct a minor compatibility glitch when its author abandoned it.

Comment: Got it - I interpret this as 'manually' making several `coxph` models to construct a multi-state model, which `muhaz` can then be used to extract hazard rates from each `coxph` - vs. making a model in, say, `mstate` and feeding that into `muhaz`.  Thanks for the guidance here!

Comment: The muhaz package has no notion of a Cox model. It'should be thought of as a counterpart to forming a K-M curve. It handles raw data and does non-parametric stuff to it. Cox modeling is "semi-parameteric", and has additional statistical assumptions embedded in it.

Comment: @NickBraunagel: You might want to work with the `survival::basehaz` function. It would still require added work to construct your desired time-conditioned instantaneous risk estimate from the cumulative hazard.

Comment: Regarding the part of your answer concerning risk estimate for a member of the stratum, if I only want to know the probability of a patient experiencing an event between `time=now` and `time=now+10`, could I just take the decrement in survival (`S(now) - S(now+10)`)?  And I would choose the appropriate curve on the plot depending on how many events the patient has already experienced.

Comment: Sounds right to me.

Comment: I have done some editing; please ensure it still says what you want it to.  Also, note that under the formula, you have "numerator" twice.  I believe you mean the latter to be *denominator*.

Comment: Quite so on numerator/denominator. Thanks again. My training was as a physician so I never got conversant with LateX. I'm still an ASCII-art kind of guy. You've perhaps noticed that I've taken on the role of "survival-analysis"-consultant over on SO. I only got here because I was referred over by the questioner.